# Wait for async result inside synchronous function

Tags: android, kotlin, concurrency, socket.io, kotlin-coroutines

I need to return a value within an asynchronous callback. This value is acquired asynchronously as a websocket acknowledgement, and I can't find a way to block that callback's execution until the value is retrieved... I have tried all combinations of coroutines to no avail.

```
override fun someAsyncCallback() : String 
{
   var myAsyncValue = ""

   socket.emit(event = "someEvent", callback = { result ->
       //This is an asynchronous callback
       myAsyncValue = result
   })

   //Insert way to wait for the async value to be set 
   
   return myAsyncValue
}
```

Comment: Can this function be a suspend function? Which net library are you using?

Comment: @Tenfour04 It cannot be a suspend function since those need to be called from coroutines, and the top-level callback is not running in a coroutine. I am using socket.io.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the function is called from a thread where it's OK to block. You can use a CountDownLatch to wait for it.

```
override fun someAsyncCallback() : String 
{
   var myAsyncValue = ""
   val latch = CountDownLatch(1)

   socket.emit(event = "someEvent", callback = { result ->
       myAsyncValue = result
       latch.countDown()
   })

   latch.await()
   
   return myAsyncValue
}
```

You can also pass a timeout to the `latch.await()` method so this doesn't block indefinitely.

Comment: I already tried the `CountDownLatch` but that didn't work. The event callback never fires while the thread is blocked.

Comment: What if you wrap the `socket.emit` call in `thread { }`?

Comment: Same thing, the callback never fires even if `socket.emit` is launched from another thread. It seems the socket acknowledgement callback always happens on the original thread, which means any interruption prevents it from running...

Comment: Ok, so maybe instead of running the callback on the calling thread, it uses a cached reference to whatever thread it is calling this interface method on. In that case, I don’t know how to work around it. I don’t use socket.io.